# Tag Synonym Suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Since I don't have the reputation required yet, does some moderator agree with these linkages?

- [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) = [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)?
- [text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text) = [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)?

Anyone else, please feel free to add your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and no.

1. arithmetic = math?

   Afaik, all arithmetic is math, but not all mathematics is arithmetic.
2. text = string?

   In programming, texts are normally represented as strings, but not all strings are texts, and texts puts a different emphasize. "Write a program which figures out the language of a text." for example.